# PasswordResetConfirmView return 200 success reponse but password is not changed in django

Tags: python, django

I just implemented reset password in my app using `django.contrib.auth.views`. I'm on the half way now but there is one problem with `PasswordResetConfirmView`.

When I requested for password reset by entering the email, my app sent a link to the email that i just input. After I clicked on that link, it redirected me to a view which is `PasswordResetConfirmView`. After entered the new password, new confirm password, and submit the form it returns 200 success response without redirecting me to the `PasswordResetCompleteView` and also the password is not changed yet.

I think i miss something but can't figure it out so I'm here asking for help.

urls.py

```py
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

urlpatterns = [
    path('reset-pasword/',
          auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(
              template_name="password_reset/password_reset.html"
          ),
          name="password_reset"),

    path('reset-password-done/',
          auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(
              template_name="password_reset/password_reset_done.html"
          ),
          name="password_reset_done"),

    path('reset-password-confirm/<uidb64>/<token>/',
          auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(
              template_name="password_reset/password_reset_confirm.html"
          ),
          name="password_reset_confirm"),

    path('reset-password-complete/',
          auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(
              template_name="password_reset/password_reset_complete.html"
          ),
          name="password_reset_complete"),
]
```

[Updated]
here is the response

```sh
"POST /user-account/reset-password-confirm/NA/ah5gne-48bf0be46e301fc88c52e0fb060b0f0b/ HTTP/1.1" 200 16764
```

Everything works perfectly fine except password is not changed.

Comment: Your HTTP réponse return success, before going any further, could you try changing your password through the admin panel and login and do the same exact same thing but with password reset view ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include [`auth.urls`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.views),

```
path('...your path...', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
```

---

**Note:**
Inorder to use custom templates you need to make a directory named `registration` inside the `templates` directory,

```
path(
    'password_reset',
    auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(),
    name='password_reset'
),  # allows a user to reset their password by generating a one-time use link
path(
    'password_reset_done',
    auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(),
    name='password_reset_done'
),   # after password reset email sent
path(
    'password_reset_confirm/<uidb64>/<token>',
    auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(
            template_name='registration/password_reset_confirm.html'
    ),
    name='password_reset_confirm'
),  # present a form to enter new password
path(
    'password_reset_complete',
    auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(
            template_name='registration/password_reset_complete.html'
    ),
    name='password_reset_complete'
),    # inform success
```

[Some reference](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/09/19/how-to-create-password-reset-view.html)

Comment: that will use the default django password reset template and I don't want that. Also I think it's not related to my problem.

Comment: You're already using it sort of :) Updated my answer...